Generated pdfs unexpectedly marked as different by git
If I generate an empty git repo, generate a pdf using ggplot2 using the code below, commit the pdf and rerun the same code, the pdf file will be marked as modified even though the code is the same and for what I can tell, the pdf is 'identical'.
Why is that? Is there any way I can circumvent this? I'd like git to keep track of a few diagnostic PDFs that I generate and while I understand that pdfs can look very similar and be different, I cannot understand why this behaves like this.
library(tidyverse)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point()

ggsave(plot = p, filename = "mtcars_plot.pdf", width = 6, height = 4)


Pdfs (can) include metadata like the time the file was created.
